# Clean up AD with CSV as input

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My HR-department has provided me with a list of several thousand users with updated "company" and "location" fields. I would like to clean up AD with this file as basis. 
I'll have to do some kind of "soft matching" on names because I'm not sure all names match 100%. 
How would I go about scripting this so this?

Sune, Norway:)

Comment: So you just expect that smebody do it for you ? What do you try so far ?

Comment: You are of course right JPBlanc. I should not expect someone to do this for me:) I am not. I was just looking for some starting-points to verify that I've started in the right direction (or not). I will post my script-block as soon as I am back in the office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Windows 2008 server, it includes a native AD management module for powershell. So you don't need the Quest pack.

```
import-module activedirectory
$users = import-csv path file.txt

foreach($user in $users)
{    
    set-aduser -id "$($user.name)*" --replace @{Company=$user.Company;physicalDeliveryOfficeName=$user.location}
}
```

This does assume that you want the location information written to the "office" field in users and computers.
The * on the ID should do a soft search.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Quest ActiveRoles Server PowerShell CmdLets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx). Check out the [Get-QADUser examples](http://wiki.powergui.org/index.php/Get-QADUser).

```
$updates = Import-Csv updates.txt

foreach ($update in $updates) {
    $user = Get-QADUser -SamAccountName $update.SamAccountName
    $user.Company = $update.Company
    # Location is not an attribute of the user
    #$user.Location = $update.Location 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both.
I did, however end up with the following complete script (hope this can be of use to someone else):

```
Clear-Host

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
Add-PSSnapin quest.activeroles.admanagement -ErrorAction silentlycontinue

$file = "\Scripts\employees.csv"        #  Location of the input file
$file2 = "\Scripts\employees2.csv"      # Temp file
$logfile = "\Scripts\logfile.txt"   # log file
remove-item $logfile -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Get-Content $file | Out-File -Encoding UTF8  $file2                         # Convert to UTF8 (we don't touch the original inputfile)
$ListEmployees = Import-Csv $file2 -Delimiter ";"                           # Import the file to CSV

foreach ($ListEmployee in $ListEmployees) {
$ListDisplayName = $ListEmployee.firstname + " " + $ListEmployee.lastname

if($ADemployee = Get-QADUser -displayname $ListDisplayName -IncludedProperties employeeid )
{
    ## CHECK NAME
    if($($ADEmployee.displayname) -eq $($ListDisplayName))
    { 
        echo "MATCH: $($ADEmployee.displayname)" 
    }

    ## CHECK COMPANY
    if($($ADEmployee.company) -ne $($ListEmployee.company))
    { 
        echo "       CHANGE   - Company: '$($ADEmployee.company)' to '$($ListEmployee.company)'" 
        Set-QADUser -identity $($ADEmployee.samaccountname) -Company $($ListEmployee.company) -WhatIf
    }
    else
    {
        echo "       OK       - Company     : no change '$($ListEmployee.company)'"
    }

    ## CHECK OFFICE
    if($($ADEmployee.office) -ne $($ListEmployee.office))
    {
        echo "       CHANGE   - Office '$($ADEmployee.office)' to '$($ListEmployee.office)'"
        Set-QADUser -identity $($ADEmployee.samaccountname) -Office $($ListEmployee.Office) -WhatIf
    }
    else
    { 
        echo "       OK       - Office      : no change '$($ListEmployee.office)'"
    }

    ## CHECK MOBILE
    if( $listemployee.mobile -match '\S' )
    {
        if($($ADEmployee.mobile) -ne $($ListEmployee.mobile))
        {
            echo "       CHANGE   - Mobile  : '$($ADEmployee.mobile)' to '$($ListEmployee.mobile)'"
            Set-QADUser -identity $($ADEmployee.samaccountname) -Mobile $($ListEmployee.mobile) -WhatIf
        }
        else
        { 
            echo "       OK       - Mobile      : no change '$($ListEmployee.mobile)'"
        }
    }

    ## CHECK EMPLOYEEID
    if($($ADEmployee.employeeid) -ne $($ListEmployee.employeeid))
    {
        echo "       CHANGE   - EmployeeID: '$($ADEmployee.employeeid)' to '$($ListEmployee.employeeid)'"
        Set-QADUser -identity $($ADEmployee.samaccountname) -ObjectAttributes @{employeeID = $($ListEmployee.employeeid)} -WhatIf

    }
    else
    {
        echo "       OK       - EmployeeID  : no change '$($ListEmployee.employeeid)'"
    }
    $match++
}
else
{
    if($EXContact = Get-Contact $ListDisplayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        echo "MATCH CONTACT: $ListDisplayName (contact)"

        ## CHECK MOBILE
        if( $listemployee.mobile -match '\S' )
        {
            if($($EXContact.Mobilephone) -ne $($ListEmployee.mobile))
            { 
                echo "       CHANGE   - Mobile : '$($EXContact.Mobilephone)' to '$($ListEmployee.mobile)'"
            }
            else
            { 
                echo "       OK       - Mobile ; No change ($($ListEmployee.mobile))"
            }
        }

        ## CHECK COMPANY
        if($($EXContact.company) -ne $($ListEmployee.company))
        { 
            echo "       CHANGE   - Company: '$($EXContact.company)' to '$($ListEmployee.company)'"
        }
        else
        {
            echo "     OK       - Company : No change($($ListEmployee.company))"
        }

        ## CHECK OFFICE
        if($($EXContact.office) -ne $($ListEmployee.office))
        { 
            echo "       CHANGE   - Office '$($EXContact.office)' to '$($ListEmployee.office)'"
        }
        else
        {
            echo "       OK       - Office : No Change($($ListEmployee.office))"
        }       
        $contactmatch++
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$ListDisplayName" | Out-File $logfile -Append
        echo "NO MATCH: $ListDisplayName" 
        $nomatch++
    }
}
$i++
}
echo " "
echo "List contains $i accounts"
echo "Accounts: $match matches"
echo "Contacts: $contactmatch"
echo "No Match: $nomatch"
```